# Alternative to imagesc and angle of matlab in python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matplotlib

I have this code that plots an image in matlab. How this code would be in python using matplotlib pyplot? I am not getting the same plot using it. My matplotlib gives an allblack and white image using numpy.angle.

```
f1 = figure(66); imagesc(-angle(O),[-.6,1]); axis image; colormap gray; axis off
```

Obs: variable O is an array of complex numbers.
Thank you guys.

Comment: How would you expect complex numbers to be mapped to color?

Comment: That os why I am trying to get it's phase angle beforing showing its colors. This code is perfect on Matlab, I am only struggling on translating it

Comment: `numpy.angle` should give you the angle. You could provide a [mcve] to see where the problem is.

Answer (score -1):

The reason it is going to black & white is because the values you are plotting are outside of the range -0.6 to 1.

numpy.angle might be returning in degrees, or the phase angles are just simply different for some reason - say, 180 degrees out of phase.